# Can't set any perl version as default in Macports

Tags: macports, perl

I installed perl_select, which I don't think, I've had to do for any other application. Despite that I cannot set any version of Perl as default as I easily can for python.

```
% port echo installed | grep ^perl
perl5                          @5.28.3_0+perl5_28
perl5.28                       @5.28.3_2
perl5.30                       @5.30.3_1
perl5.32                       @5.32.1_1
perl5.34                       @5.34.0_0
perl_select                    @0.3_0

% port select --list perl
Available versions for perl:
        none (active)
```

Comment: See https://trac.macports.org/ticket/29763 looks like a longstanding issue

Comment: @mmmmmm 10 years! Wow, that's almost impressive.